# iOS IPA web distribution delay

Tags: ios, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

My IPA distribution web portal is working well but few months ago it's too slow... The system alert "Install app ..." is shown after one or two minutes.

Everything works fine except the delay.

Anyone struggling with the same issue?

Testers are frustrated by the waiting ...

I've tried to went trough all tutorials about IPA web distribution and everything looks good. When I download the .plist file or .ipa file it is downloaded in 1-3 seconds. Also installation is ok. But I can't get rid of the 1-2 minutes delay of installation alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use diawi.com for IPA sharing. If you've same issue on diawi it's mean is there any issue of IPA but if not that's mean issue in you portal. Web developer can find out issue in your portal

Comment: In my scenario, this is not the way because we have internal network for distributing. I'm asking mainly for the case somebody has similar issue with the delay...